# Effective optical depth using Beer-Lambert law for non-linear attenuation?

Tags: optics, gas, absorption, attenuation

Currently I have a gas with a density that follows and inverse square law in distance, $r$. Given that I know the mass attenuation coefficient of this gas, I wish to calculate an effective optical depth using a modified version of the Beer-Lambert Law that uses mass attenuation coefficients (as seen here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_attenuation_coefficient) :

\begin{equation}
 \tau = \frac{\alpha \rho_{gas}(T)l}{\rho} = \frac{\alpha M p(T)}{\rho R T} \int \frac{1}{x^2} dx
\end{equation}
Where $\alpha$ is the mass attenuation coefficient for the solid phase of the gas [cm$^{-1}$], $\rho$ is the mass density of the solid phase of the gas, $l$ is the path length, $M$ is the molar mass of the gas, $p(T)$ is the pressure of the gas as a function of temperature, $R$ is the ideal gas constant and $T$ is the temperature of the gas. $\rho_{gas}$ is the mass density of the gas itself and can be extracted from the ideal gas law:
\begin{equation}
  \rho_{gas} = \frac{p(T)M}{RT}
\end{equation}

The integral emerges from my attempt at rewriting the first equation for a non uniform attenuation, that I have here due to the inverse square law effecting the density of the gas.

However, I am now concerned that units no longer balance here since $\tau$ should be unitless. Can anyone help guide me here?

Comment: Your first equation has two $\rho$ Are these the same quantities or different ones? If it's the same you have $\frac{\rho}{\rho}$ which is unitless so $\tau$ must have the same units as $\alpha$

Comment: @Hilmar I have added the missing path length in the initial equation.

Comment: @Hilmer I have also rewritten the equations to accurately represent the methodology found in the derivation of the Beer Lambert law (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer%E2%80%93Lambert_law)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you set the density of the gas as
$$\rho_{gas}\propto\frac{1}{x^2}$$
To make the units work out, you need a constant of proportionality to make this an equality:
$$\rho_{gas}=\frac{\beta}{x^2}$$
The units of $\beta$ can be whatever is needed unit-wise, just like $G$ in the Newtonian gravity equation. Newton said that the force of gravity between two objects is proportional to the product of their masses and inversely proporitonal to their squared distance
$$F \propto \frac{mM}{r^2}$$
To make this into an equation, we add an empirically measured proportionality constant
$$F = G\frac{mM}{r^2}$$
The units of $G$ are whatever they need to be to balance the equation.